# Как сделать что бы потоки дожидались выполнения

Tags: java, многопоточность

```
@Configuration
```

@EnableAsync
public class AppConfig {

```
@Bean(name = "threadPoolTaskExecutor")
public TaskExecutor threadPoolTaskExecutor() {
    ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
    executor.setCorePoolSize(4);
    executor.setMaxPoolSize(4);
    executor.setThreadNamePrefix("thread-");
    executor.initialize();
    executor.setAwaitTerminationSeconds(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
    executor.setWaitForTasksToCompleteOnShutdown(true);
    return executor;
}
```

Сам класс, в нем использую  CountDownLatch latch , но получается что выполняется только один поток, хотел использовать Future но когда Подключаю свой бин с threadPoolTaskExecutor" то у TaskExecutor taskExecutor не доступен метод submit .

```
@Service
```

public class ThreadExecutorService {

```
private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ThreadExecutorService.class);

@Autowired
@Qualifier("threadPoolTaskExecutor")
TaskExecutor taskExecutor;
@Autowired
CameraService cameraService;
CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);

public List<CameraInfoThread> generateCameraReport() throws JsonProcessingException, InterruptedException {

    List<Camera> list = cameraService.getListCameras();
    List<CameraInfoThread> cameraInfoList = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        CameraInfoThread cameraInfoThread = new CameraInfoThread(list.get(i));
        taskExecutor.execute(cameraInfoThread);
        latch.await();
        cameraInfoList.add(cameraInfoThread);
    }
    return cameraInfoList;
}

private class CameraInfoThread implements Runnable {
    Camera camera;
    CameraInfo cameraInfo = new CameraInfo();

    public CameraInfoThread(Camera camera) {
        this.camera = camera;
    }
    public void run() {
        try {
            log.info("START");
            cameraInfo.setId(camera.getId());
            SourceDataUrl sourceDataUrl = cameraService.getSourceDataUrl(camera.getSourceDataUrl());
            cameraInfo.setUrlType(sourceDataUrl.getUrlType());
            log.info("/////////////////////");
            cameraInfo.setVideoUrl(sourceDataUrl.getVideoUrl());
            TokenDataUrl tokenDataUrl = cameraService.getTokenDataUrl(camera.getTokenDataUrl());
            cameraInfo.setValue(tokenDataUrl.getValue());
            cameraInfo.setTtl(tokenDataUrl.getTtl());
            log.info("END");
            latch.countDown();
        } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "CameraInfoThread{" +
                "cameraInfo=" + cameraInfo +
                '}';
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Исполняется только первый поток заполняется сущность и помещается в лист, другие сущности null. Если без делать CountDownLatch latch то ничего не заполняется

Comment: Из вопроса не ясно, что вы пытаетесь реализовать. Вопрос именно в том "что", а не "как". В частности, чего вы пытаетесь достичь используя `CountDownLatch`?

Comment: Я пытаюсь сделать что бы метод run заполнил обьект, или точнее в каждом потоке создавались обьекты Camerainfo. Но не знаю как в моем коде сделать управление потоками, т.к. они не могут нормально заработать. CountDownLatch я использовал просто для проверки в качестве эксперимента понять, работает ли вообще или нет мой код, работает запускается  первый поток  и в нем создается обьект. А дальше все останавливается. Вопрос в том как сделать что бы все заработало без CountDownLatch. Вообще какой механизм использовать , примера я так и не нашел

Answer (score 1):

С использованием `CountDownLatch` это делается так.

```
public List<CameraInfoThread> generateCameraReport() throws JsonProcessingException, InterruptedException {

    List<Camera> list = cameraService.getListCameras();
    List<CameraInfoThread> cameraInfoList = new ArrayList<>();

    // важно, чтоб каждый поток мог уменьшить latch
    CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(list.size());
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        CameraInfoThread cameraInfoThread = new CameraInfoThread(list.get(i), latch);
        taskExecutor.execute(cameraInfoThread);
        cameraInfoList.add(cameraInfoThread);
    }
    latch.await();  // важно ждать после того, как все потоки запущены
    return cameraInfoList;
}

private class CameraInfoThread implements Runnable {
    Camera camera;
    CameraInfo cameraInfo = new CameraInfo();
    final CountDownLatch latch; 

    public CameraInfoThread(Camera camera, CountDownLatch latch) {
        this.camera = camera;
        this.latch = latch;
    }
    public void run() {
        try {
            log.info("START");
            cameraInfo.setId(camera.getId());
            // обработка c заполнением cameraInfo
            log.info("END");
            latch.countDown();
        } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Альтернативный вариант это сделать бин `threadPoolTaskExecutor` не `TaskExecutor`, а `AsyncTaskExecutor` (просто поменять тип в конфигурации, `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor` реализует оба интерфейса). `AsyncTaskExecutor` позволяет делать `submit`, который возвращает `Future`.

Comment: [CameraInfoThread{cameraInfo=CameraInfo{id=1, urlType='LIVE', videoUrl='rtsp://127.0.0.1/1', value='fa4b588e-249b-11e9-ab14-d663bd873d93', ttl=120}}, CameraInfoThread{cameraInfo=CameraInfo{id=20, urlType='null', videoUrl='null', value='null', ttl=null}}, CameraInfoThread{cameraInfo=CameraInfo{id=null, urlType='null', videoUrl='null', value='null', ttl=null}}, CameraInfoThread{cameraInfo=CameraInfo{id=2, urlType='null', videoUrl='null', value='null', ttl=null}}]   Заполнилась только первая камера, в моем коде срабатывало также, видимо латч тут совсем не подходит

Comment: В вашем коде ожидаемо не работало. Тут все правильно. Что-то делаете не так. В логе "START" и "END" для всех камер появляется? Может у вас исключение случается, а вы его игнорируете

Comment: Заработало не там ожидание поставил, но 1 обьект из трех не собирался, добавил слип в методе run
          и заработало
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                latch.countDown();